# regex end search on specific character

Tags: python, regex, search

So I have a string that I am trying to search through using re.search. The string is combined of an Id and then a string after it. So it looks like this: `<@randomId> string after`

I am using the regex pattern `"^@(|[WU].+?)>(.*)"` in my `re.search` method to try and get two different groups. The first group is the id, minus the `< >`. So it would just be `"@randomId"`. And the second group would be the `"string after"` text that comes after the Id. So if the text I am passing into `re.search` is `"<@QWE1234> do this"` I want to match and return `"@QWE1234"` and `"do this"`.

With the regex I am using I am getting a return type of None, and when I add in `<` to the regex pattern, so it looks like this: `"^<@(|[WU].+?)>(.*)"` I get the whole string.

Comment: Are only certain characters allowed in the randomId?

Comment: It is just uppercase letters and numbers and also the @. No special characters besides the @

Answer (score 1):

To match 2 capturing groups, you could remove this part `|[WU]` from your regex and add `\s+` to account for the following whitespace characters so that you don't have to trim that match.

Your regex could look like[`^<(@.+?)>\s+(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/u08eoD/1)

Or instead of using `.+?`, you could use `[^>]+`

[`<(@[^>]+)>\s+(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/lLeoZK/1)

That would match

- Match `<`
- `(@[^>]+)` Capture in  group 1 and `@`, then not `>` using a negated character class
- Match `>`
- `\s+` Match on or more whitespace characters
- `(.*)` Capture zero or more characters in group 2 (If there has to be at least 1 character following you could use `.+` instead)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/YHSQCN49105)

If you only want to allow uppercase characters and numbers, you could use:

[`<(@[0-9A-Z@]+)>\s+(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/8q8UVf/1)

Answer (score 0):

`^` matches the start of the string, so you would want your pattern to be either `"^<@(|[WU].+?)>(.*)"` or `"@(|[WU].+?)>(.*)"`. Note that the pattern is a bit more complicated than it needs to be, `"^<@(.+?)>(.*)"` should work. You might also want to pull the `@` inside the group, because that way it would match the output you described.

So then your code would be something like:

```
match = re.search(r"^<(@.+?)>(.*)")
if match is None: 
   pass # handle the case that it is not found
else:
   randomId = match.groups(1)
   textAfter = match.groups(2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I just figured that out myself.

Answer (score 0):

So the regex `"^<@(|[WU].+?)>(.*)"` was the correct one, but I was not returning the correct search group from the re.search method. I had to specify `return (matches.group(1), matches.group(2).strip())`